# EF6 + stored procedure = timeout exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6

My environment is VS 2012, C#, EF6 and SQL Server 20012.

I have got a stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyName
    @Param1 int,
    @Param2 bit,
    @param3 bit,
    @param4 uniqueidentifier    
AS
```

it use Select, Update, delete command.

On server side I use a `*.edmx` model and EF 6.x EntityObject generator
and 15s for timeout

```
 ObjectContext.MyName(param1, param2, param3, param4);
```

If I use SQL Server Management Studio, then the stored procedure executes in 1-3 sec, if I used EF6, I get a timeout exception.

I set timeout to 60, 90, 120sec and more, but it did not help.

Could someone help? What do I do?

**Update 1:**

I catch: `EntityCommandExecutionException`

An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

**Inner exception:**

"Timed out (Timeout). The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

It call the SP:

```
[EnableClientAccess()]
[RequiresAuthentication()]
public partial class MyService : OCEntityService<MyEntities>
{
public override string DBName
{
    get { return "MyDbName"; }
}

public new string EntityConnectionString
{
    get
    {
        EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb =
            new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(this.ConnectionString)
            {
                Metadata =
                    "res://*/Entities.Model.csdl|res://*/Entities.Model.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Model.msl",
            };
        ecsb.ProviderConnectionString += "MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";

        return ecsb.ConnectionString;
    }
}

protected override MyEntities CreateObjectContext()
{
    return new MyEntities(EntityConnectionString);
}

public void DeleteObject()
{
    ObjectContext.MyName(param1, param2, param3, Guid.NewGuid());
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
}
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

**My connection string**

`metadata=res://*/Entities.Model.csdl|res://*/Entities.Model.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="data source=.;initial catalog=MyDb;persist security info=False;user id=user;workstation id=localhost;packet size=4096;max pool size=500;network library=dbmssocn;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"`

I found the following:

I use the stored procedure in a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{

    try
    {
        DeleteObject(item.Id, param2, param3, Guid.NewGuid());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        To log...
    }

}

...
public void DeleteObject(...)
{
    ObjectContext.MyName(param1, param2, param3, Guid.NewGuid());
    ObjectContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

I set timeout = 600

For a first item, the stored procedure executed 45 - 55 sec (i saw  by the SQL Server Profiler) and all data has been deleted or updated but I'm getting the exception the above. The other items executed 2-3 sec excelent without exception.

I see the problem as follows:

When a Sql is executing first query, he is building the Query Execution Plan and it takes a long time. But i can not find cause for timeout exception

Comment: Is your call to the stored procedure running inside a transaction?

Comment: No, I don't use a transaction.

Comment: If you show us the exception message and put your code that calls the SP you are more likely to get some help.

Comment: Did you put timeout value in your connection string ? if so that's a known bug, i.e. it's ignored... try setting it directly on the context like ObjectContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 180;

Comment: I set `ObjectContext.Database.CommandTimeout = 600` and it did not help

Comment: Did it take 10mins to return the timeout? i.e. 600 seconds (not milliseconds) p.s. show your entire connection string plz

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74898/discussion-between-evgeniy-kozlov-and-paul-zahra).

Comment: It helped 
`ObjectContext.Database.CommandTimeout`
I use a SilverLight app and I mixed up a Sql timeout exception  and  a Invoke timeout exception  :)

Comment: Sweet... by the way do you know you have a duplicate entry in your conn string? MultipleActiveResultSets=True;

Comment: :) it's a typo, I pressed the Ctrl+V twice. The working conn string is correct!